# wikitools parsing error

Tags: python, mediawiki

I'm using `wikitools` package to parse the wikipedia. I just copy this example from documentation. But its not working. When I run this code. I get following error. 
`Invalid JSON,trying requesting again`. Can you please help me ? thanks

```
from wikitools import wiki
from wikitools import api
# create a Wiki object
site = wiki.Wiki("http://my.wikisite.org/w/api.php") 
# define the params for the query
params = {'action':'query', 'titles':'Papori'}
# create the request object
request = api.APIRequest(site, params)
# query the API
result = request.query()
```

Comment: Is that the entirety of the code?  When I run it I get `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found trying request again in 5 seconds
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found trying request again in 10 seconds` -- not the error you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"http://my.wikisite.org/w/api.php"` is only an example, there is no MediaWiki under that domain. Try with `"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"` which searches in the English Wikipedia.